# Change output directory when the current directory is full

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am busy with making a time lapse machine out of a Raspberry pi and the Pi Camera module.
I have a working script which will save .jpg files with a specific name to a specific directory. Due my good idea to take every second a photo during 4 weeks, I will need a lot of space.

Does anyone know how I automatically can change the directory once the USB device is full and change the save directory to another USB device.

Later I will add some LEDs to the GPIO pins so I now when I have to change a USB stick and insert another one so the directory can be set again to the first USB device when the second is full.

Thanks! I will show you the result!

Comment: Have you considered using logrotate or a batch script to move the older files, instead of changing directory.

Comment: no, I haven't considered.  I am not familiar with logrotate, but I think that it will not be a good option because copying all files will require more CPU usage and more battery power.